# Low coverage percentage

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest

I'm new to Python testing and I have a simple project for classes.  The problem is that I have to check my coverage, and for some reason it is very low: 4%.

I don't really undestand why. I read that it means that my tests do not cover the code I wrote.

This is my code:

```
class Morse:
    def coding(self, message):
        MORSE_CODE = {'A': '.-', 'B': '-...',
                      'C': '-.-.', 'D': '-..', 'E': '.',
                      'F': '..-.', 'G': '--.', 'H': '....',
                      'I': '..', 'J': '.---', 'K': '-.-',
                      'L': '.-..', 'M': '--', 'N': '-.',
                      'O': '---', 'P': '.--.', 'Q': '--.-',
                      'R': '.-.', 'S': '...', 'T': '-',
                      'U': '..-', 'V': '...-', 'W': '.--',
                      'X': '-..-', 'Y': '-.--', 'Z': '--..',
                      '1': '.----', '2': '..---', '3': '...--',
                      '4': '....-', '5': '.....', '6': '-....',
                      '7': '--...', '8': '---..', '9': '----.',
                      '0': '-----', ', ': '--..--', '.': '.-.-.-',
                      '?': '..--..', '/': '-..-.', '-': '-....-',
                      '(': '-.--.', ')': '-.--.-', "&": ".-...",
                      "'": ".----.",
                      "@": ".--.-.",
                      ":": "---...",
                      ",": "--..--",
                      "=": "-...-",
                      "!": "-.-.--",
                      "+": ".-.-.",
                      '"': ".-..-.",
                      'Ą': ".-.-",
                      "Ć": "-.-..",
                      "Ę": "..-..",
                      "Ł": ".-..-",
                      "Ń": "--.--",
                      "Ó": "---.",
                      "Ś": "...-..."

                      }
        translation = ''
        for letter in message:
            if letter.upper() != ' ':
                translation += MORSE_CODE[letter.upper()] + ' '
            else:
                translation += ' '

        return translation

    def decoding(self, morse):
        MORSE_CODE = {'A': '.-', 'B': '-...',
                      'C': '-.-.', 'D': '-..', 'E': '.',
                      'F': '..-.', 'G': '--.', 'H': '....',
                      'I': '..', 'J': '.---', 'K': '-.-',
                      'L': '.-..', 'M': '--', 'N': '-.',
                      'O': '---', 'P': '.--.', 'Q': '--.-',
                      'R': '.-.', 'S': '...', 'T': '-',
                      'U': '..-', 'V': '...-', 'W': '.--',
                      'X': '-..-', 'Y': '-.--', 'Z': '--..',
                      '1': '.----', '2': '..---', '3': '...--',
                      '4': '....-', '5': '.....', '6': '-....',
                      '7': '--...', '8': '---..', '9': '----.',
                      '0': '-----', ', ': '--..--', '.': '.-.-.-',
                      '?': '..--..', '/': '-..-.', '-': '-....-',
                      '(': '-.--.', ')': '-.--.-', "&": ".-...",
                      "'": ".----.",
                      "@": ".--.-.",
                      ":": "---...",
                      ",": "--..--",
                      "=": "-...-",
                      "!": "-.-.--",
                      "+": ".-.-.",
                      '"': ".-..-.",
                      'Ą': ".-.-",
                      "Ć": "-.-..",
                      "Ę": "..-..",
                      "Ł": ".-..-",
                      "Ń": "--.--",
                      "Ó": "---.",
                      "Ś": "...-..."

                      }
        translation = ""
        words = morse.split("   ")
        for morse_word in words:
            chars = morse_word.split(" ")
            for char in chars:
                for k, v in MORSE_CODE.items():
                    if char == v:
                        translation += k
            translation += " "

        return translation.rstrip()
```

And tests:

```
class TestMorse(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.temp = Morse()
    def test_morse_single_letter(self):
        morse=".- "
        inputed_data = "A"
        self.assertEqual(morse, self.temp.coding(inputed_data))
    def test_morse_word(self):
        morse=".-- --- -.. .- "
        inputed_data = "woda"
        self.assertEqual(morse, self.temp.coding(inputed_data))
    def test_morse_numbers(self):
        morse=".---- ..--- ...-- "
        inputed_data="123"
        self.assertEqual(morse,self.temp.coding(inputed_data))
    def test_morse_sentence(self):
        morse=".- .-.. .-  -- .-  -.- --- - .- "
        inputed_data = "Ala ma kota"
        self.assertEqual(morse, self.temp.coding(inputed_data))

    def test_morse_empty(self):
        morse = ""
        inputed_data = ""
        self.assertEqual(morse, self.temp.coding(inputed_data))

    def test_morse_punctuation_marks(self):
        morse = "--..-- "
        inputed_data = ","
        self.assertEqual(morse, self.temp.coding(inputed_data))

    def test_morse_punctuation_marks_2(self):
        morse = ".-... .----. .--.-. -.--.- -.--. ---... --..-- -...- -.-.-- .-.-.- -....- .-.-. .-..-. ..--.. -..-. "
        inputed_data = "&'@)(:,=!.-+\"?/"
        self.assertEqual(morse, self.temp.coding(inputed_data))
    def test_morse_with_polish_marks(self):
        morse = '.-.- -.-.. ..-.. .-..- --.-- ---. ...-... '
        inputed_data = "ĄĆĘŁŃÓŚ"
        self.assertEqual(morse, self.temp.coding(inputed_data))
    # -------
    # DECODING
    # ----
    def test_morse_decoding_single_letter(self):
        expected_output = "A"
        morse = ".-"
        assert_that(self.temp.decoding(morse)).is_equal_to(expected_output)

    def test_morse_decoding_single_word(self):
        expected_output = "ALIBABA"
        morse = ".- .-.. .. -... .- -... .-"
        assert_that(self.temp.decoding(morse)).is_equal_to(expected_output)
    def test_morse_decoding_sentence(self):
        expected_output = "ALA MA KOTA"
        morse = ".- .-.. .- / -- .- / -.- --- - .-"
        assert_that(self.temp.decoding(morse)).is_equal_to(expected_output)
    def tearDown(self):
        self.temp = None


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Is the coverage so low because I'm using only some of the letters of the alphabet? What do I have to do to make my coverage % higher?

Output of the coverage report:

```
Name                  Stmts   Miss  Cover
-----------------------------------------
tests\test_morse.py      54     52     4%
-----------------------------------------
TOTAL                    54     52     4%
```

Comment: have you tested for an invalid character in coding?  invalid character in decoding?  As a side note, why repeat MORSE_CODE?  You can either move it two a class level constant or at least to an instance level constant, to simplify your code and possibly increase your coverage.

Comment: @itprorh66 i did test for invalid characters like arrays, objects, booleans now. A  i also put MORSE_CODE in __init__, yet the coverare report is low, now even lower beause only 2%.

Comment: If the tests are really run would have a much higher coverage, something  is wrong with your coverage setup, I would say.

Comment: What tool is being used to compute coverage?

Comment: i just write `coverage report` in the console

Comment: You are likely not running the tests with coverage. See the `coverage run` example: https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/6.2/

Comment: @KristofferBakkejord what is a proper way to call `coverage run`, because when i type it in termial i get : `Nothing to do`.

Comment: The docs I linked to shows the commands needed, for pytest it should be `coverage run -m pytest tests` (if you have test files in a `tests` dir).